# Get rid of NaT values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like shown below

```
                               mean
comp_name  date                      
Appdynamics 2012-05-01 00:18:15.910000
            2012-05-01             NaT
            2012-05-01             NaT
            2012-05-02 00:20:12.145200
            2012-05-02             NaT
            2012-05-02             NaT
```

Here the comp_name and date form multiindex. I want to get rid of the NaT values and obtain only those rows where the mean(timedelta64) is not NaT.

```
                               mean
comp_name  date                      
Appdynamics 2012-05-01 00:18:15.910000
            2012-05-02 00:20:12.145200
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: does `dropna()` not work for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`pandas.notnull()` takes a series and returns a Boolean series which is True where the input series is not null (None, np.NaN, np.NaT). Then you can slice a dataframe by the Boolean series:

```
df[pandas.notnull(df['mean'])]
```

Comment: How can you check for 2 columns at once, eg, `df['mean', 'score']`?

Comment: Depending on what you want:    
`df['mean','score'].isnull().any(axis=1)`     or 
`df['mean','score'].isnull().all(axis=1)`

Comment: In recent versions, it's better to do the slicing in this way: `df.loc[df.mean.notnull()]`

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas 1.4.1 `dropna` gets rid of `NaT` values. Source: [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and I am using it. So now it is as simple as

```py
df = df.dropna()
```